# Should ufw default configuration allowing mDNS and UPnP for service discovery be changed?

Tags: ufw, upnp, mdns

The default configuration files of ufw in Ubuntu 18.04 ( /etc/ufw/before.rules and /etc/ufw/before6.ruls ) accept service discovery for UPnP and mDNS.

File /etc/ufw/before.rules

```
...
# allow MULTICAST mDNS for service discovery (be sure the MULTICAST line above
# is uncommented)
-A ufw-before-input -p udp -d 224.0.0.251 --dport 5353 -j ACCEPT

# allow MULTICAST UPnP for service discovery (be sure the MULTICAST line above
# is uncommented)
-A ufw-before-input -p udp -d 239.255.255.250 --dport 1900 -j ACCEPT
...
```

File /etc/ufw/before6.rules

```
...
# allow MULTICAST mDNS for service discovery
-A ufw6-before-input -p udp -d ff02::fb --dport 5353 -j ACCEPT

# allow MULTICAST UPnP for service discovery
-A ufw6-before-input -p udp -d ff02::f --dport 1900 -j ACCEPT
...
```

I read some articles which say that UPnP involves security risks.
Should I disable these rules ? In that case, is it enough to comment them out or should I have to change ACCEPT by DROP or REJECT ?

Thanks in advance for any clue.

Answer (score 1):

Really, the question here is "Do you need UPnP?"

If you need UPnP for some logical reason then leaving those rules alone is fine.  However, you can comment them out as you indicated if you don't need or don't want UPnP service discovery to work.

Most networks don't have UPnP enabled by default anymore, so there's some mitigations there, however UPnP *is* a security risk because it can open up holes into your network while your device is using UPnP.  It's usually best to leave UPnP disabled.  However, keep in mind that 18.04 is also 4 years old and the `ufw` defaults may have changed since 18.04 so the rationale for this proposed question of yours may no longer apply in later Ubuntu releases.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I agree with you. I will investigate whether in current Ubuntu releases these defaults have changed.

Comment: Up to Ubuntu 22.04 server, these defaults haven't been changed.

Comment: @RomualdoCaruso note that while the multicast packets themselves may be UPnP related, *most* environments (other than home networks where UPnP is present for gamers, etc.) where systems tend to be using Server (corporate networks, etc.) don't use UPnP and have it disabled, so even if a UPnP request goes to the network, it gets ignored.  You can disallow those rules yourself by commenting htem out in the rules, but then UPnP is not actually working anyways, so.  There's some extra consideration stuff at play depending on where you're deploying and what network configs are at play.

Comment: I only wanted to point out that it should be better that those lines were commented out by default in a server installation.

Answer (score 0):

For the second part of the question, it is enough to comment them out, because in that case those packets continue their filtering though the *ufw-after-input* chain, then though the *ufw-skip-to-policy-input* chain which eventually drops them.